# Match two dataframes and fill the column value in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

I have two excel file. I have to match them based on particular column and fill the other column. I explain you in the example.

Example:
2 excel files:

`monitered call.xlsx`  In this excel 2 sheets are there, 1. print add 2. digital

`digital C2D.xlsx`  single sheet is there Sheet1

monitered calls.xlsx:

[image]

digital C2D.xlsx

[image]

I have to match `Caller Number`  with `CONTACT` and if both are matching then take the `REMARK` from 2nd excel and paste in first excel.

In the last save the updated data into monitered calls.xlsx in the same sheet.

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'D:\Users\SPate233\Downloads\Alka\monitored calls.xlsx', sheet_name='digital')
df1 = pd.read_excel(r'D:\Users\SPate233\Downloads\Alka\digital C2D.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Comment: Please give a minimum example to help us get started, or atleast prepare the data for us...

Comment: you can do that directly in excel

Comment: @Jayvee but I have to it by python

Comment: It doesn't help that none of the numbers actually match the other dataset in your example. It also doesn't help that they are screenshots instead of markdown sample data

Comment: I know numbers are not matching. but I need logic to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read and store both sheets in Pandas dataframes and use merge to get the result you are looking for. The pandas documentation has some really nice examples: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html. And in case you are not familair with joins, check this out: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp.

Comment: Can you please give me sample code. It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: df = pd.read_excel(r'D:\Users\SPate233\Downloads\Alka\monitored calls.xlsx', sheet_name='digital')
df1 = pd.read_excel(r'D:\Users\SPate233\Downloads\Alka\digital C2D.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1') 


df1['CONTACT'] = '91' + df1['CONTACT'].astype(str)

df_concat = pd.concat([df1, df])

print(df_concat)